# Video plays fine on VLC but black screen on Totem

Tags: video, vlc, ffmpeg, totem

I have created a video (with no audio track) by C++ code which plays fine on `VLC` but shows black screen (with the same duration) on `Totem`.

What is wrong with the file?

```
totem video0.mp4  --gst-debug-level=2


0:00:00.165734411 11969 0x7f3f10003b80 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3489:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.166118552 11969 0x7f3f10003b80 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3489:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.196680481 11969 0x7f3ee00ea2d0 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:2651:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux0> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
0:00:00.196977258 11969 0x7f3ee00ea2d0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2396:gst_base_src_update_length:<source> processing at or past EOS
```

and debug level 3:

```
totem video0.mp4  --gst-debug-level=3


0:00:00.195766358 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.195808156 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.209930090 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3489:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.210300987 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3489:gst_base_src_start_complete:<source> pad not activated yet
0:00:00.210692379 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.210706890 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.220489949 12019 0x7fc9000e0d90 WARN                 qtdemux qtdemux.c:2651:qtdemux_parse_trex:<qtdemux0> failed to find fragment defaults for stream 1
0:00:00.220565181 12019 0x7fc9000e0d90 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2396:gst_base_src_update_length:<source> processing at or past EOS
0:00:00.223242462 12019 0x7fc8f8004540 FIXME           videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:946:gst_video_decoder_drain_out:<pngdec0> Sub-class should implement drain()
0:00:00.223316018 12019 0x7fc8f8004540 FIXME           videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:946:gst_video_decoder_drain_out:<pngdec0> Sub-class should implement drain()
0:00:00.242389203 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.242430385 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.242445206 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.279566412 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.279682024 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
0:00:00.279695802 12019 0x55cf0f81b6d0 FIXME                    bin gstbin.c:4149:gst_bin_query: implement duration caching in GstBin again
```

**Update 1**

`ubuntu-restricted-extras` is already installed:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (65).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

**Update 2**

output information:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams -show_format video0.mp4


[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=png
codec_long_name=PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image
profile=unknown
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=14457931/419310000
codec_tag_string=mp4v
codec_tag=0x7634706d
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=rgba
level=-99
color_range=pc
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=29/1
avg_frame_rate=419310000/14457931
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=43373880
duration=481.932000
bit_rate=74462385
max_bit_rate=74462385
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=13977
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=video0.mp4
nb_streams=1
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=481.932000
size=4485908727
bit_rate=74465422
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2mp41
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.83.100
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: If it plays in VLC probably  nothing is wrong. VLC uses its own set of codecs and it seems that specific file is supported. It may not be in other software that relies on codecs installed in the system. Additional codecs are usually installed with the `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelBay, symptomatically sounds like an unavailable (or corrupt) codec.

Comment: @MichaelBay, updated the post. Is there any other possibility? (I have used PNG codec).

Comment: That's part (or related to) QuickTime which should have been included in the "restricted extras" but maybe the way you coded it isn't supported by the standard codecs and only by VLC's set of codecs.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, I have created the video by code. Do you mean uploading it?

Comment: Yes, or show info about it: `ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams -show_format video0.mp4`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, please see my second update.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing PNG in MP4. Maybe consider Matroska instead.